# Loading image as Sprite from SD card in AndEngine GLES2

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I have searched all the forums but i am unable to get any working code. I want to load an image as sprite from SD Card in AndEngine GLES2.Can any one provide me a code?
Any Help will be Appreciated. Here is what i have tried.

```
File imageFile = new File(pFilePath);
BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(myCxt.getTextureManager(),540 , 960 , TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = new FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource(imageFile);
TextureRegion textureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture,fileTextureSource ,0,0, true);
```

This code is working for andEngine1 but in GLES2, line given below is generating compile time error
 "Construtor FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource(file) is undefined"
`FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = new FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource(imageFile);`

How can i load an image as sprite from SD Card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution of the problem.
FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource is changed in AndEngine2.
Here is the code that worked for me

```
File imageFile = new File(pFilePath);
BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),displayMetrics.widthPixels , displayMetrics.heightPixels , TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(imageFile);
Engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(texture);
TextureRegion textureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture,fileTextureSource ,0,0, false);
screenShot = new Sprite(130, 230, textureRegion, myCxt.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just direct copy from my old project (it is inside activity class), it load image from internal storage, you can change it to `createFromExternalStorage()`. IIRC, `createFromExternalStorage()` and `createFromInternalStorage()` have the same parameters, but different locations. The image file is located at '/data/data/your_package/files/' (if internal) or '/sdcard/Android/your_package/files/' (if external).

```
BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
mBeanRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture, FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource.createFromInternalStorage(this, "bean.png", 0, 0), 0, 0);
texture.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File imageFile = new File("sdcard/image");
BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(width , height , TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = new FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource(imageFile);
TextureRegion textureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture,fileTextureSource ,0,0, true);
```

Comment: Gaurav, you copied the same code given above from another post.
This code is working in AndEngine1 but not for GLES 2.
But thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes i was just trying to help u .I thought it might possible u haven't seen this post...